# Casting for Lambda: BiConsumer<Integer, Integer>

Tags: java, lambda

I get a compiler failure like this:
 The method accept (Integer, Integer) in the type BiConsumer is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object). How can I cast two Integer-inputs, so the compiler accepts them as `<Integer, Integer>`?

I'm getting the failure in the following code:

```java
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class ExceptionHandlingExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numberArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int key = 2;
        calc(numberArray, key, wrapperForLambda( (a, b) -> System.out.println(a / b) ));
        // Type Safety: The expression of Type BiConsumer needs unchecked conversion to conform to unchecked BiConsumer<Integer, Integer>
    }

    private static void calc(int[] numberArray, int key, BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {
        for (int i : numberArray) {
            consumer.accept(i, key);
        }
    }

    private static BiConsumer wrapperForLambda(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {
    // BiConsumer is a raw type. References to generic type BiConsumer<T, U> should be parameterized       
        return (a, b) -> consumer.accept(a, b) ;   
    // [Compilier-error] The method accept (Integer, Integer) in the type BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object) 
    }
}
```

I want to get rid of the compiler-error:
The method accept (Integer, Integer) in the type BiConsumer is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object)

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `numberArray` in `calc()` where it is coming from? is it declared as a static variable?

Comment: What's the purpose of `wrapperForLambda` method?

Comment: Is this eventually a case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/141148)?

Comment: The hole point of this lambda construct is to shorten the code. Therefore I tried not to put my original method into a try-catch-block, which would blow up the code. Instead I create a wrapper, which is here a stub, but could catch an ArithmeticException - in this case if someone invokes a division with 0 . The hole point of the wrapper is here to outsource several exception-handling methods in the wrapper without repeating them in the code time and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the raw type `BiConsumer`. Declare the method as

```
private static BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> 
        wrapperForLambda(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {   
    return (a, b) -> consumer.accept(a, b);
}
```

When you use the raw `BiConsumer`, Java uses it as the target type for the lambda expression `(a, b) -> consumer.accept(a, b)`. The consequence of that is that the parameters `a` and `b` are assumed to be of type `Object` (raw types, remember!), which won't work with your `consumer` `BiConsumer` which expects `Integer`s.

If this is supposed to be a general-purpose method, you can make the method generic:

```
private static <T, U> BiConsumer<T, U> 
        wrapperForLambda(BiConsumer<T, U> consumer) {   
    return (a, b) -> consumer.accept(a, b);
}
```

Comment: I didn't vote, but what's the point in `return (a, b) -> consumer.accept(a, b);` when you can simply write `return consumer;` (which means you don't need that method at all)?

Comment: @Eran Thanks, I agree. But I think `return consumer;` works rather as a happy accident. The OP shouldn't use the raw type. On the "why", I assumed that the *wrapper* did more than what we're seeing (and in that assumption may be my mistake)

Comment: I agree that the raw type shouldn't be used, but given the code the OP posted, I don't see why the `wrapperForLambda` method is required at all (and eliminating it will also eliminate the raw type).

Comment: I assume that the OP posted/tried to post a MCVE, so we can't recognize the reason for that method - but that is just my assumption - so I think this answer is valid too

Comment: In my comment attached to my original post I added an explation, how I try to add a bunch of exception handling routines to the wrapper. Essentially I try to work out a kind of design pattern here. 
Thank you ernest_k ! With your suggestion the code compiles and all others remarks vanish. Your solution simply hits the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's the purpose of `wrapperForLambda`. You don't need it. Simply call `calc` as follows:

```
calc(numberArray, key, (a, b) -> System.out.println(a / b));
```

And the error in `wrapperForLambda` can be eliminated with:

```
private static BiConsumer wrapperForLambda(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {
     return consumer;
}
```

but I still think this method is pointless.

P.S. I'm assuming the loop in `calc` method should iterate on the `someNumbers` array, not `numberArray` (which is a local variable of your `main` method).

Answer (score 0):

You can use as

```
    return (a, b) -> consumer.accept((Integer) a, (Integer) b);
```

Before Java 1.5, you couldn't even do this:

```
    int a;

    Object x = (Integer) a;
```

The compiler would complain that a is of a primitive data type, and therefore cannot be cast to an object.

Starting with Java 1.5, Java introduced the concept of automatic boxing. So, the following became OK:

```
    int a;

    Object x = (Integer) a;
```

Because the compiler knows how to convert from a primitive int to the boxed type Integer automatically; and from Integer to an Object it's, well, not a problem.

However, what you're trying to do:

```
    int a;

    Object x = (int) a;
```

Is basically telling the compiler to avoid boxing. You explicitly tell the compiler to leave a as an int, and put a reference to that int into an Object. The compiler isn't designed to deal with such a case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the method `wrappedForLambda`, as @Eran correctly mentions.

Just use the lambda expression directly.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numberArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int key = 2;
    calc(numberArray, key, (a, b) -> System.out.println(a / b) );
    // Type Safety: The expression of Type BiConsumer needs unchecked conversion to conform to unchecked BiConsumer<Integer, Integer>
}

private static void calc(int[] someNumbers, int key, BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {
    for (int i : numberArray) {
        consumer.accept(i, key);
    }
}
```

If this does not compile for some reason (old JDK or old eclipse), cast to Integer explicitly:

```java
calc(numberArray, key, (Integer a, Integer b) -> System.out.println(a / b) );
```